# How can I set up a casual proxy

Tags: windows-xp, proxy, security

I have a friend living abroad who can't access certain country specific sites.

He wants to decide who can use/not use it.

So my question to  you is:

Is there a small, simple application that can function as a proxy from Windows XP (home edition) that also is secure?

edit: what about other ports except port 80? Specifically streaming contents from sites such as Spotify?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Psiphon](http://psiphon.ca/) for your "friend" :)

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking about a proxy but your post certainly doesn't make it clear why.

A simple and free proxy can easily be created using the Apache web server. Yes, I know that may not sound right but Apache is actually a very good proxy server. Couple that with the security Apache is capable of your friend should be able to achieve his goals. A bit of Googling will reveal numerous articles showing just how to go about it.

Comment: I don't know if I got the skills or capabilities, interest to keep updating Apache locally